irreducible representations of Group generate left ideal in Groupring CG.
Let W be the vectorspace of an irreducible representation of a group G.$char_W(g)$ denotes the character of the representation W. With $$e:=dim W \cdot \frac{1}{|G|}\sum\limits_{g \in G} \overline {char_W(g)}g$$ I=(e) is supposed to be a minimal left ideal of the groupring $\mathbb{C}G$. I know that e is an idempotent but I have trouble using this to proof the minimality of I. Can anyone put me on the right track?

Are you familiar with the Artin-Wedderburn decomposition of $\mathbb{C}[G]$?

Now I am, somewhat at least. I also read that this somehow can work with Maschke's theorem which is something I´'m more familiar with.

Great. Unfortunately I don't believe this statement as written, and I think the correct statement is that $I = (e)$ is a minimal two-sided ideal. Where did you get this statement from?

That it is supposed to be a left minimal ideal I got from: "Representation Theory" by William Fulton, Joe Harris, page 37.

The part of the text you're quoting is confusingly written, but actually it does not claim that $I = (e)$ is a minimal left ideal, which is good because it's not true. This is what it says (Fulton and Harris' Representation Theory, remarks after Proposition 3.29, p. 37):

...any irreducible representation is isomorphic to a (minimal) left ideal in $\mathbb{C}G$. These left ideals are generated by idempotents.

This is true. Explicitly, in terms of the Artin-Wedderburn decomposition $\mathbb{C}[G] \cong \prod \text{End}(V_i) \cong \prod M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$, a choice of minimal left ideal isomorphic as a representation to $V_i$ (these are not unique) is generated by any diagonal matrix in $M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$ with one entry equal to $1$ and the others equal to $0$. All possible choices are generated by the matrices of rank $1$.

In fact, we can interpret the projection formulas of the last lecture in the language of the group algebra: the formulas say simply that the elements
$$\dim W \cdot \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \overline{\chi_w(g)} \cdot e_g \in \mathbb{C} G$$
are the idempotents in the group algebra corresponding to the direct sum factors in the decomposition of Proposition 3.29.

These idempotents are not the idempotents in the previous sentence generating minimal left ideals. In terms of the Artin-Wedderburn decomposition they correspond to the identity matrices in each $M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$, and the left ideals they generate are not minimal but are isomorphic to a direct sum of $\dim V_i$ copies of $V_i$. And in fact the next sentence clarifies this:

To locate the irreducible representations $W_i$ of a group $G$ [not just a direct sum of $\dim(W_i)$ copies], we want to find other [emphasis mine] idempotents of $\mathbb{C} G$.


Thanks, that cleared up quite a bit of my confusion but I still don't get the whole picture. So I proofed that the matrices you described do in fact generate a minimal left ideal of  $ \prod M_{n_{i}}(C) $. I also proofed that since we have a ring-isomorphism with $\mathbb{C}G$ they must correspond to a minimal left ideal in $\mathbb{C}G$. What I'm still not sure about is what these ideals look like in $\mathbb{C}G$.

Besides that I'm also not quite sure how exactly the isomorphism between such an ideal in $M_{n_{i}}(C)$ and the representation $V_i$ is formally constructed. After all don't we get different ideals for the choices of the diagonal element we choose to be non zero? If we pick the j-th Element the elements of the ideal in question are matrices where the j-th column is non-zero, if we pick the k-th diagonal element then we get matrices with the k-th column non-zero.

@VeryGenericUsername: I'm not sure either. The Artin-Wedderburn isomorphism is very inexplicit! It's quite magical that it exists at all. You could in principle write down a more explicit version of it by choosing a basis of each irreducible representation but that sounds unpleasant to me. We do get different ideals for different choices but they are all isomorphic as representations.
